# if attr is something then get it's text using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

Plz see below my xml, am trying to parse it using jquery

XML

```
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>        
    <wplc:field id="gender">MALE</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="doc_source">default</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="degree">M.D.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="defaultcontext">/poc</wplc:field>       
    <wplc:field id="docid">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="title">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="language">English</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="doctortype">Plastic Surgery</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">3D Surface Motion Capture</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition"></wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Kinematic Motion Capture</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Cleft Lip</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Cleft Palate</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Velocardiofacial Syndrome</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
```

JQUERY

```
success : function(data){

            $(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function(){
                 $(this).find('wplc\\:field, field').each(function(){


                    if($(this).attr('id') == "condition"){                            

                    }
                 });                   
            });
        }       
});
```

here am trying to get the title(Alex Kane) where the id="condition" is empty.
How can I achieve this??

Comment: what is `atom:entry` or `entry`? Need to show full xml structure. Hard to help with traverses for structure we can't see

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started.

```js
$(data).find('atom\\:entry').each(function(){
    // collection of "conditions"
    var $conditions = $(this).find('wplc\\:field[id="condition"]');
    // filter empty conditions and get length
    var hasEmptyCondition = $conditions.filter(function(){
        return !$.trim($(this).text())
    }).length;

    var emptyName
    if(hasEmptyCondition){
        emptyName = $(this).find('wplc\\:field[id="title"]').text();
        alert(emptyName +' has empty condition')
    }    
});
```

Note that due to not having xml namespacing defintions the following demo has slightly modified tag names (`:` changed to `-`)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/q09bQh8HHsS7kEM8cdNQ?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just select the parent of the `id` element which contains the name you are looking for, then loop over the child elements to find the specific element.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $entry = $xml.find( "id:contains('Alex Kane')" ).parent();

$entry.children().each(function(i, e) {
    if ( $.trim($(e).text()) === "" && $(e).attr('id') === "condition" ) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L3kua597/)